# javascript alert method

Tags: javascript

Why is the following line not alerted?

```
  <script>
  alert(x);//this line is not executed or alerted  ???.It should have alerted "undefined" 
  console.log(x)//reference error 
  var y="maizere";
  alert(y);//this line is also not executed or alerted  ???

  </script>
```

Any undeclared variables are treated as global variable in javascript right?

Comment: See your JS error console.

Comment: Maybe because it's in a code block in a SO question...
Joking aside, we couldn't tell you, since we can't see the context of your code. Please post all your relevant code.

Comment: how are you calling that js?

Comment: The x value is undefined... declare x previus the alert... `var x = "any value"; alert(x);` and the code of y alert works.... Greetings.

Comment: There's a difference between a variable being *undeclared* and having an *undefined* value. Your `x` is never declared, e.g., with a `var x;` declaration.

Comment: what do you have in your console. An error? Tell us what error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
alert(x);//this line is not executed or alerted  ???.It should have alerted "undefined"
```

That's incorrect. This line raises a `ReferenceError` because there's no variable `x`.

Contrast this with situation:

```
var obj = {};
alert(obj.x); // undefined - there's no attribute x
```

Comment: but undeclared bar are the treated as global variable

Comment: @MaizerePathak If you did `alert(window.x)`, it would work (in the same way `obj.x` would), but `alert(x)` does not, without a declaration.

Comment: @Maizere: Only when you *assign* to them, not when you are trying to *read* them.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting `undefined` and `undeclared` confused.

The variable `x` is undeclared - it has not been declared in code yet, so

```
alert(x);
```

will raise an error in the likes of `'x' is not declared`.

Your code should read

```
<script>
  var x;
  alert(x);//this line is not executed or alerted  ???.It should have alerted "undefined" 
  var y="maizere";
  alert(y);//this line is also not executed or alerted  ???
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you put inside an `alert` call should be defined. If it is not (your case) then an error is thrown. So, you should define the variable first. For the errors, you should check a JavaScript (browser) console.

```
var x = "Test";
alert(x); // shows
var y = 123;
alert(y); // y also shows, because there is no error thrown inside the alert for x
```